# How to force PERCENTOF to spill results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lambda

The new `PERCENTOF` function in Excel is much welcomed; however, I'm trying to overcome one of its limitations. I don't want to use multiple formulas to achieve a set of results, but I haven't found an easy way to spill them with a single one.

[image]

I have tried `=PERCENTOF(INDEX(A2:A6,SEQUENCE(5)),A2:A6)`, hoping it spills each percentage separately, but the `data_subset` argument doesn't support it. It only does the same as `=PERCENTOF(A2:A6,A2:A6)` by returning 100%.

Is there a way?

Comment: Didn't hear about this new function yet, but you may try: =MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(z,PERCENTOF(z,A2:A6)))

Comment: I'm afraid that produces a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: The map formula works for me. I guess the reason the original formula doesn't spill is that the first argument of the call to percentof is generally an array.

Comment: Shorter syntax, though not using `PERCENTOF()` at all - `=BYROW(A2:A6,SUM)/SUM(A2:A6)`

Comment: @user11222393 Yes, it does work now. It was because before you edited your formula, the one I copied and pasted had `z` in an extra argument unnecessarily.

Comment: @Statto sorry for that, it was a matter of seconds till I realized mistake and didn't think you have already copied that!

Comment: `=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(a,PERCENTOF(a,A2:A6)))` works, as well as `=GROUPBY(A2:A6,A2:A6,PERCENTOF)` which includes the array itself followed by the individual PERCENTOF results. I tried leaving out totals `=GROUPBY(A2:A6,A2:A6,PERCENTOF,,0)` but that makes my Excel crash, but it's still Beta phase.